# Best way to pass around manager class

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

Say that i have a class called "ConfigManager" which will handle the config file for my application, like to load it and reload it.
Which design pattern would be best to pass around and access the class from everywhere in my project?
I'm currently thinking on a simple singleton pattern with a static getter method for easy access, or that i initiate the class in the "Main/Startup" class and then pass the "Main/Startup" class around in order to access the "ConfigManager" class.

This might be little bit fussy, but i hope your guys understand what i mean.

Comment: Are you using spring?

Comment: Does this ConfigManager class have attributes that change throughout the application? If the values in it are always the same, you don't need to instantiate anything, you can just have static methods that load and reload the config and call the class from anywhere.

Comment: No I'm not using spring and yes, some attributes will change during runtime.

Comment: easy way singelton - best way dependency injection

Comment: Please post code of your class.